# Azure Static Web App appends my href links

Tags: azure, web, single-page-application, azure-static-web-app

Hi I'm using Azure Static Web App to load the documentation of a product I'm working on.

I have the need to add some links to the html pages but even if the hrefs have an absolut path, when clicking on the link the page is not found since an automatic concatenation between the current page link and the absoluth path I've added is performed.

Inspecting the html code, the link is well written, but if I click it, the concatenation is automatically performed.

[image]

There is not javascript code and seems to be fault of AzureStaticWebApp, since it works properly when I open the html files locally.

Answer (score 0):

I've spot the error. Dumb error.

I've wrongly written the html url to the page I would like to link. Instead of using `https://` there was a single `/` ->`https:/`

Setting the correct url fix my problem